# How can we get the example questions asked here?

Tags: discussion, questions

I took a look back at the site when it was in the [Definition](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65204?phase=definition) phase, and noticed that there were a lot of good example questions. Unfortunately, many have not been asked here. I'm guessing that part of the reason is that many people who posted questions did not commit to the site and thus are not active in the private beta. But how can we get people who posted good example questions and have committed to the site to post their example questions?

Comment: I am of the opinion that we go ahead and ask them

Answer (score 2):

If it has already been asked. Do not ask it.

If not:

[image]

Users who asked questions during the definition phase may have done it for the sake of definition. Ask it yourself. If you are too conscious about asking it yourself, make it community wiki.